# opensuse leap shutdown does not shut down correctly?

Tags: opensuse, shutdown, battery

I have a new laptop (lenovo thinkpad t460p) With both Windows 10 and opensuse leap installed. If I shutdown my computer under opensuse leap (using shutdown button or even `/sbin/shutdown 0`); it appears to shut down completely. The next day however my battery is completely empty. When I shut down under windows; the battery is completely full the next day. I have no real ideas of where to look to solve this problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: Interesting. Seems to work for me on X250.

Comment: @choroba: I've been trying to edit bios to disable suspect settings; but since it works under windows; I think bios is not the origin